# Undefined reference to OPENSSL_sk_num ERR for Apache 2.4.54

Tags: apache-2.4

I am unable to compile Apache HTTPd-2.4.54 on Linux platform.

My system config:

- OS: 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
- Openssl: OpenSSL 1.1.1q 5 Jul 2022

I am getting the following error, even when I try with OpenSSL 3x, I am getting the same error.

Please kindly help me.

Commands I used:

```
[root@abc.com]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[root@abc.com]# systemctl stop apache2.service
[root@abc.com]# ./configure --prefix=/app/Apache2.4 --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/bin/openssl --enable-so --with-openssl=/usr/local/bin/openssl
[root@abc.com]# Make & make test


httpd-2.4.54/modules/mappers -prefer-non-pic -static -c ab.c && touch ab.lo
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99 -pthread \
-o ab ab.lo /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.la -ldb-5.3 -lexpat -ldb-5.3 /usr/lib64/libapr-1.la -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -ldl
ab.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
ab.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ab.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
ab.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ab.o: In function `ssl_state_cb':
ab.c:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `SSL_in_init'
ab.o: In function `ssl_print_cert_info':
ab.c:(.text+0x890): undefined reference to `X509_get_version'
ab.c:(.text+0x8d5): undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
ab.c:(.text+0x92b): undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
ab.o: In function `test':
ab.c:(.text+0x4fae): undefined reference to `SSL_in_init'
ab.o: In function `main':
ab.c:(.text+0x5c24): undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
ab.c:(.text+0x644c): undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
ab.c:(.text+0x674e): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
ab.c:(.text+0x675d): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
ab.c:(.text+0x67f8): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ab.c:(.text+0x6886): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Regards,
Rose.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what distribution and version you're using? It looks like you're using a RHEL variant (like RHEL 7 or CentOS 7), but on these platforms the service is named `httpd`.

Comment: RHEL 7, Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

so I did tried to do it myself

Install dev tools

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

Install required dependencies

```
yum install wget tar unzip zip pcre pcre-devel expat expat-devel -y
```

Download it

```
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/httpd/httpd-2.4.54.tar.gz
```

Extract

```
tar -xzvf httpd-2.4.54.tar.gz
```

Get the extras

```
cd httpd-2.4.54/srclib
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org//apr/apr-1.7.0.tar.gz && wget https://dlcdn.apache.org//apr/apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf apr-1.7.0.tar.gz && tar -xzvf apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
mv apr-1.7.0 apr && mv apr-util-1.6.1 apr-util
```

Build

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin
make && make install
```

Hopefully it's working for you.

Also the error you are having is because you ran `./configure ...` before installing `expat-devel`

In my opinion the safest choice for you is to use the already existent package provided by CentOS

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexander, I followed your steps, but I am still getting the same errors, please help me.

Comment: run JUST `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin`, without specifying those arguments, that you mentioned above. why are you trying to install apache on /app/ ? that most likely doesn't exist or it may not be in your $PATH ?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I used ./configure --prefix=/app/Apache2.4 parameter only. That is where "/app/Apache2.4"  my current version is 2.4.43 installed

Comment: are you using a docker container ?

Comment: No, It's straightforward Linux RHEL 7 system.  Thank you.

Comment: have you fixed it ? follow my steps again

Comment: I followed and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I never said you should use configure with this path - /app/Apache2.4 - follow my exact steps

Comment: Sure, I will try one more time and let you know, Thank you.